# Async method that calls in ViewModel causes deadlock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I do requests to Github Api so I have async methods, these do this job. Before it, I always called they in method, that calls from command(actually DelegateCommand). But now I wanna do request in ViewModel because I need to display list on page. I am using Prism to wire view and viewmodel. 
Because I can't make viewmodel async, I can't use await word, so I tried to do something like gets result from task, or task.wait. But with this I have the same result. My app stop works with white display when it did request. I read some info about that and I understood that call async method in not async method is bad, and it causes deadlock, but I don't know what to do with this. And I think deadlock causes that app stop works.
Here is method where app die:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<RepositoryModel>> GetRepositoriesAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var reposRequest = new RepositoryRequest { Sort = RepositorySort.FullName };
        var gitHubRepos = await _gitHubClient.Repository.GetAllForCurrent(reposRequest);  //async request, don't say about name convention, it is not my method.
        var gitRemoteRepos = new List<RepositoryModel>();
        foreach ( var repository in gitHubRepos )
        {
            var repos = new RepositoryModel();
            repos.RepositoryTypeIcon = GetRepositoryTypeIcon(repository);
            gitRemoteRepos.Add(repos);
        }
        return gitRemoteRepos;
    }
    catch ( WebException ex )
    {
        throw new Exception("Something wrong with internet connection, try to On Internet " + ex.Message);
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        throw new Exception("Getting repos from github failed! " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And here is viewmodel:

```
public class RepositoriesPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private INavigationService _navigationService;
    private readonly Session _session;
    public ObservableCollection<RepositoryModel> Repositories { get; }
    private readonly RepositoriesManager _repositoriesManager;
    public RepositoriesPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, ISecuredDataProvider securedDataProvider)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        var token = securedDataProvider.Retreive(ConstantsService.ProviderName, UserManager.GetLastUser());
        _session = new Session(UserManager.GetLastUser(), token.Properties.First().Value);
        var navigationParameters = new NavigationParameters { { "Session", _session } };

        _repositoriesManager = new RepositoriesManager(_session);
        var task = _repositoriesManager.GetRepositoriesAsync();
        //task.Wait();
        Repositories = task.Result as ObservableCollection<RepositoryModel>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use TPL in constructor

Comment: Don't use `Task.Result` from the main (GUI) thread.

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using my [`NotifyTask<T>` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async), which provides a data-bindable wrapper around `Task<T>`. I explain this pattern more completely in my [article on async MVVM data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

```
public class RepositoriesPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
  private INavigationService _navigationService;
  private readonly Session _session;
  public NotifyTask<ObservableCollection<RepositoryModel>> Repositories { get; }
  private readonly RepositoriesManager _repositoriesManager;
  public RepositoriesPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, ISecuredDataProvider securedDataProvider)
  {
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    var token = securedDataProvider.Retreive(ConstantsService.ProviderName, UserManager.GetLastUser());
    _session = new Session(UserManager.GetLastUser(), token.Properties.First().Value);
    var navigationParameters = new NavigationParameters { { "Session", _session } };

    _repositoriesManager = new RepositoriesManager(_session);
    Repositories = NotifyTask.Create(GetRepositoriesAsync());
  }
}

private async Task<ObservableCollection<RepositoryModel>> GetRepositoriesAsync()
{
  return new ObservableCollection<RepositoryModel>(await _repositoriesManager.GetRepositoriesAsync());
}
```

Note that with this approach, your data binding would use `Repositories.Result` to access the actual collection. Other properties are also available, most notably `Repositories.IsCompleted` and `Respositories.IsNotCompleted` for showing/hiding busy spinners.

Comment: Thank you a lot. And for your articles also.